# Windows installed on 17" MacBook shows bad resolution.

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, resolution

I installed Windows 7 using BootCamp but I can only choose the 800x600 or 1024x768 resolution. Can I get any other resolutions? Is there any driver I need to install. These resolutions don't look good on my screen, in fact, they look very bad.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the BootCamp drivers haven't been installed within Windows as those are the default software resolutions for graphics cards without drivers.

The BootCamp drivers can be found on the original set of DVDs that came with the machine, which will be updated to the latest versions once installed in Windows.

You can download BootCamp 3.2 for Windows, and the 3.3 update here, although 3.2 should update once you're online anyway. http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macoscomponents

Comment: What he said ^^